# How to input an existing value into an input field in React for an edit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an existing Task with a title and a description, and I want to navigate to an edit form. By default I want the existing title and description values to populate the inputs using React. The important piece of this code I'm asking about is `value={task.title}`. Please ignore how the data is being pulled in (I'm new to React and I'm experimenting). The onChange and onSubmit handles work correctly, but the error obviously indicates I'm doing it wrong and it does cause occasional bugs.

I've tried abstracting those values into some sort of formValues state as well, but no matter how the values are being input, if the `value={howeverIDoIt}` is being directly manipulated I get the error.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { HEADERS, TODO_URL } from '../urls';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const TaskEdit = () => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState({});
    const { id } = useParams();
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${TODO_URL}/api/tasks/${id}/`, {headers: HEADERS})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
              setTask(responseJson);
          });
    }, []);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setTask(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const body = {
            'title': e.target.form[0].value,
            'description': e.target.form[1].value
        }
        fetch(
            `${TODO_URL}/api/tasks/${id}/edit/`,
            {
                headers: HEADERS,
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }
        ).then(res => res).catch(err => err);
        history.push(`/task/${id}`)
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={task.title} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea onChange={handleChange} value={task.description}></textarea>
            </div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default TaskEdit;
```

I have tried putting in a default value for useState like so: `useState({title: 'title', description: 'description'})` but that doesn't prevent the error, nor does adding this edit form into the Task.js component, where `task` is most definitely defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={task.title} />
```

Your `handleChange` method is:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        setTask(e.target.value)
}
```

When your `onChange` fires, your `task` state will be set to a String (the value of `<input />`)

So when you are referencing `task.title` after your `onChange` fires, it will be undefined. The same is true for `task.description`.

Try this:

```
const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
  setTask({...task, title: e.target.value})
}

const handleDescriptionChange = (e) => {
  setTask({...task, description: e.target.value})
}

<input type="text" onChange={handleTitleChange} value={task.title} />
<textarea onChange={handleDescriptionChange} value={task.description} />
```

Alternatively, you could split up the `task` state to `title` and `description`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks so much! So just for other people's future reference since my post is kinda all over the place (as is my React knowledge), using your onChange methods with a default state of `useState({title: '', description: ''}) fixes the error. I saw all over the internet about the default state using empty strings, which wasn't working because of how my onChange method was making other aspects of my task object undefined. Thanks so much!